# YII drag and drop file upload

Tags: jquery, file-upload, yii, drag-and-drop

I have a form which have a file type to upload a file. But I need something cool and useful... where we can drag and drop. I need to disable all page (transported black screen) during upload (for don't allow to do nothing to user, only cancel upload process) and showing a progress bar. So during file upload we'll show full screen black transparent in over level that will disable all app features.

Can anybody help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use yii-dropzone for drag and drop with a bit of customization.

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii-dropzone/

Answer (score 0):

Try Yii EFineUploader extension. It is the best I've found and can be manipulated to suite your needs.

Good luck